# connection error

Tags: mysql, connection

i am connecting my php page  with data bsae but connection not eshtablish and a warning is occure . my ussername and password and hostname are correct i checked many times . i cant understand why this prob is occure. please is .. the warning is given below..

```
" Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'dewasdia'@'uni.universalworkplace.com' (using password: YES) in /home/dewasdia/public_html/main.php on line 7 fail "
```

the php code is

```
function connection()
{
mysql_connect('www.xxxx.com','xyz','xyz') or die (" fail");
mysql_select_db('dewasdia_dewas') or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: The MySQL extension has been deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have an entry in the `mysql.user` table allowing a connection from your script's host (`uni.universalworkplace.com`).

You need to grant access using something like

```
GRANT ALL ON dewasdia_dewas.*
    TO 'dewasdia'@'uni.universalworkplace.com'
    IDENTIFIED BY 'xyz';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: but how & where to do this ??

Comment: @SayyedManzoorHason How: Using the `mysql` command line utility or something like phpMyAdmin if available. Where: On your database server at `www.xxxx.com`

Comment: ok but there is syntax error " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''uni.universalworkplace.com' IDENTIFIED BY xyz'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES' at line 2 "